# Return spring mvc Model on Ajax response

Tags: spring-mvc

I am having a controller that return model objects like below
model.addAttribute("list", list);

When i click a button ajax call happens and it is goes to controller executing everything and it returns. But i don't know how to access this model object in my jsp on ajax response. When i use alert for success ajax response , I am just seeing a html kind of page.

Please give me some example or reference to achieve this

Thanks in advance

Please find my sample code snippet

### Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value='/ajax' value="POST")   
 Public @ResponseBody String displayDropdown(MyForm myform,Model model) {  
 //logic to fetch details from DB 
 List<String> list = fetchFromDB(); 
 model.addAttribute("list" list);  
 return "ajaxResponse";  
}
```

### My JSP

In a button click, having the below ajax call

```
$.ajax {  
   url:'/ajax',  
   type:'POST',   
   data: $("#myform").serialize();   
   success:function(data) {   
   alert(response);      
   }    
}
```

I want to get my model from this ajax response and use it in my jsp.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but from JSP all model attribute variables are accessible simply using `${attribute_name}`. In your case it is `${list}`

Comment: I agree we can direct access model objects ${model name}. But my controller returns to ajax call in javacript. From that ajax response i want to access my model and use it in my jsp. Please let me know if you need more info

Comment: it would be easier to understand if you post the code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use

```
console.info(model)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!
Maybe you can explain some more what it does! It's always good to have some more information provided to understand what to do! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you can access `response` with JSP. JSP is the server side and response you receive when the page is already sent to client. The only thing you can try is to use COOKIES. Set `response` in cookies and then access it from the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I will try and let you know

Comment: If I will be right, please accept and upvote the answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can easily get Model data from controller, simply

```
 @RequestMapping(value='/ajax' value="POST")   
 Public String displayDropdown(MyForm myform,Model model) {  
 //logic to fetch details from DB 
 List<String> list = fetchFromDB(); 
 model.addAttribute("list" list);  
 return "yourjsppage";  
 }


 $.ajax {  
 url:'/ajax',  
 type:'POST',   
 data: $("#myform").serialize();   
 success:function(data) {   
 $("#page-wrapper").html( data );      
 }    
 }
```

page-wrapper is your content div in jsp page. this returns all jsp page including your model. in this scenario it is also useful when you want (partial rendering) not wanting to refresh whole page but targeting specific page.